# How to use a service returning VAST xml file - getting "Unable to request ads from server. Cause: Error #2048"

Tags: xml, web-services, vast

I'm using Video Suite Inspector in [Google Interactive Media Ads](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/vastinspector_dual) , though the question might be general for services.

when i'm using this [direct url](http://demo.tremorvideo.com/proddev/vast/vast2RegularLinear.xml) , the video is valid and is played. However, when i'm using another address that representing my service that brings this xml file ( it is showing the exact xml file ) i'm getting the error:

```
(1:03:21 PM) Ads requested
(1:03:21 PM) adError Ad error (code 1103): Unable to request ads from server. Cause: Error #2048
```

for example http:/SomeAddress/MyService?id=1234 in the test line brings that me the above error , even though the files are identical

Any ideas what might be the reason for that? (the address is public and there is no problem to get the file through http:/SomeAddress/MyService?id=1234)

Hope that is clear enough,
Ido

Answer (score 1):

My problem was my crossdomain.xml file did not contained google's domain. changeing it to the following solved my problem :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```